# Jquery abort() doesn't seem to release fully

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got an intranet site that the users navigate within multiple tabs in chrome. Some of them make multiple simultaneous heavy ajax calls to load lots of data, on a fixed interval.

I use the page visibility api to make sure that if a tab is not selected when its interval fires, it just resets the interval; otherwise, it refreshes the data.

I recently added some code to abort ajax calls when a page loses visibility, if it's in the middle of refreshing.

What I've found is that even if I abort an ajax call, there's some amount of time that subsequent requests to the server from this client sit and spin. It's as though the max-connections-per-server isn't reset on abort(). (edit: Not that the server is still processing, but the browser seems to not realize that it can pull a request from the queue and process it.)

Anyone ran into this before and have a fix?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately aborting an ajax request client-side does not stop the server from processing the request. In fact, the server doesn't even know the request has been aborted by the client at all.

Some server-side frameworks allow you to check if the client is still connected, but that's unreliable at best.

You may be able to get around this by initiating a secondary ajax request to the server when you abort the first one that essentially informs the server to kill any running processes associated with the session ID you're aborting. That could get a bit tricky though, especially if you need to kill a process that is responsible for updating data - you would need to ensure that you're maintaining data integrity, rolling back any changes that were made, etc.

Comment: I'm not worried about the server, it's the client and the number of simultaneous requests that's irritating my users. The server 'seems' slow because of chrome's max-connections-per-server setting. Aborting doesn't seem to release the connection for the browser to use again.

Comment: Is it possible that your xhr object is still referenced somewhere and hanging around so that it's not cleaned up by garbage collection? That may cause the connections to not reset. You could try manually setting the variable to null to get rid of any lingering references.

Comment: Good idea, but no.. even using the console to set the xhr object to null doesn't seem to hasten the pending requests.

Comment: Okay. I'm wondering if jQuery is re-using the same XMLHttpRequest object. You could try creating a new instance of it every time by passing a function into the `xhr:` property of your `.ajax` method. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/